# Keep static data initialized in Gradle JavaExec task

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle project that executes a Java program:

```
apply plugin: "base"
apply plugin: "java"

configurations {
    javaDep
}

dependencies {
    javaDep files("${project.rootDir}/cli-app.jar")
}


task cliApp(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "some.cli.App"
    classpath = configurations.javaDep
    args("program", "args")
}
```

```java
public class App {
    private static boolean isInitialized = false;
    private static ExpensiveObject data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            data = doSomeExpensiveInitialization();
            isInitialized = true;
        }

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is `doSomeExpensiveInitialization()` runs every time the `cliApp` Gradle task is executed.  Is there a way to keep the data in memory so the data is only initialized once, and isn't recalculated as long as the Gradle daemon is alive?

Comment: What data is it? How often does it change?  Can't you just serialize it to disk?  What uses the data?  Why is it a java app?  Could you make it a custom task?

Comment: The data is a variety of different things.  The data essentially already is being de/serialized from the disk.  The Java program uses the data internally.  In the real program, the Java app is actually a dependency downloaded from artifactory, so it can't really be made a custom task.